Find duplicates from pandas column of nested lists within previous rows with multiple conditions
I'm a little confused on how to code this.
I have a dataset like this:
rules   user_list       event_time          row_number
rule1   123,244,344     2024-09-20          1
rule1   125,346,421     2024-09-19          2
rule1   125,343,431     2024-09-18          3
rule2   125,344,423     2024-09-20          1
rule2   125,346,421     2024-09-19          2
rule3   125,348,331     2024-09-20          1
rule3   125,336,221     2024-09-19          2

reproducible df
data = {
    'rules': ['rule1', 'rule1', 'rule1', 'rule2', 'rule2', 'rule3', 'rule3'],
    'user_list': ['123,244,344', '125,346,421', '125,343,431', '125,344,423', '125,346,421', '125,348,331', '125,336,221'],
    'event_time': ['2024-09-20', '2024-09-19', '2024-09-18', '2024-09-20', '2024-09-19', '2024-09-20', '2024-09-19'],
    'row_number': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['event_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['event_time'])

I am trying to build another column that counts/finds the number of user_ids from the latest rule rows (where row_number = 1) that are in other rows within the past day and where the rule is a different rule (so count duplicate users that fired on different rules within the past day).
the final table should look like this:
rules   user_list       event_time          row_number      dupe_users
rule1   123,244,344     2024-09-20          1               344
rule1   125,346,421     2024-09-19          2               125,125,346,421
rule1   125,343,431     2024-09-18          3               125
rule2   125,344,423     2024-09-20          1               125,344
rule2   125,346,421     2024-09-19          2               125,125,346,421
rule3   125,348,331     2024-09-20          1               125,125
rule3   125,336,221     2024-09-19          2               125,125

ex: user 344 was seen on rule1 2024-09-20 and on rule2 on 2024-09-20.

what have you tried so far?

tbh Georgina - I haven't gotten very far. My thought was to isolate each row_number 1, which gets the latest rule firing, and then run some kind of loop on each element in row_number 1 against each element in every other user_list row that doesn't = that same rule within the past day. I will post updates when they're worth posting

Can you break down the logic/computation for each row? It's not clear to me for example why you have 125 in the third row

@mozway you're right, that was an error - that should have been left empty

I'm not sure I get the full logic, but as far as I understand, you could use a groupby.transform with a custom function and help from collections.Counter:
from collections import Counter

def f(s):
    cnts = [Counter(x.split(',')) for x in s]
    ref = sum(cnts, start=Counter())
    out = []
    for x in cnts:
        diff = ref-x
        out.append(','.join(y for val in x for y in [val]*(diff[val])))
    return out

data['dupe_users'] = data.groupby('event_time')['user_list'].transform(f)

Output:
   rules    user_list event_time  row_number       dupe_users
0  rule1  123,244,344 2024-09-20           1              344
1  rule1  125,346,421 2024-09-19           2  125,125,346,421
2  rule1  125,343,431 2024-09-18           3                 
3  rule2  125,344,423 2024-09-20           1          125,344
4  rule2  125,346,421 2024-09-19           2  125,125,346,421
5  rule3  125,348,331 2024-09-20           1              125
6  rule3  125,336,221 2024-09-19           2          125,125


I think you got it... I'm trying to validate it with my actual data, which is very hard cuz it's much bigger, but this looks like it. thanks so much @mozway

Hey @mozway - dumb question - is this finding the users over the past 1 day? or just any duplicate user in dataset?

if you see this message, i'm stuck on the finding dupe users only over the past day. could use your help!
